# Deploying on shinyapps.io: A package dependency should not be required, yet Shiny asks for it

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny application based on an unpublished package. I have, therefore, explicitly created stand-alone functions of parts of this unpublished package. Shiny call these functions when needed. On my local machine, Shiny is not calling this unpublished package. I have even uninstalled this package to make sure that Shiny is independently functioning.

Yet, when I deploy this package to shinyapps.io, I face an error about this unpublished package is required.

I suspected that an earlier Shiny deployment of this app might have interfered and that this dependencies is an echo. So I removed that earlier version to make sure that this app is not interfering with the new app. But the same problem persists.

In summary, a package dependency should not be required, yet Shinyapps asks for it.Any idea of what is going on?

Not sure how to write a reproducible example of this particular issue.

(NB: I have posted this question [`\[here\]\[1\]`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2527) as well as [[here][2])](https://community.rstudio.com/t/deploying-on-shinyapps-io-a-package-dependency-should-not-be-required-yet-shiny-asks-for-it/35517)

Comment: Have you restarted your R session? Maybe you call a function with `package::xxx`. Hard to guess without code :-)

Comment: I did restart the R session.  But the uninstalled package still hinders the code from being deployed to shiny. However, there is a clue: I still see the package listed in the namespaces. What does that mean?

Comment: it means that you saved your session I guess

Comment: I am running Rstudio so it could be that the session is saved from last time. Will explore this possibility asap. Will get back...